# Not working background image change on hover

Tags: html, css

I saw few answer about changing image on hover and i made one programme according that but still it is not working. please suggest.

```
<style>
.nik:hover{ background-image:url(2.jpg); background-size:500px 500px; background-position:center;}
</style>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="nik" style="height:300px; display:block; width:300px; border:1 groove; background-image:url(a.jpg); background-size:300px 300px; background-position:center;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Move the contents of the inline `style` attribute to the `<style>`  part.

Answer (score 3):

You have a priority issue with your CSS.

An inline styling is always more prioritized than a styling inside a CSS file (or between *style* tags).

For further reading: [Reviewing CSS Style Priority Level](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/)

---

P.S - The best practice is not to set inline styles at all, but to use an external CSS file containing your styles at one place.

Comment: I pressed V button, ok?

Comment: I mean the "V" button next my answer from the left.

Comment: is there any other way for this becuase when i am fetching data threw db, background img is same for every td but i want to display different images according db

Comment: You can add a real image with absolute positioning and a negative z-index